# xmobar not launching via xmonad

Tags: haskell, xmonad, xmobar

I am very new to xmonad and I am trying to launch xmobar from the xmonad.hs file but I can't seem to get it to work. I have been looking all around the internet but still no solution.
The wierd thing is that I can easily launch it using the terminal and it works no problem. When I recompile xmonad with mod+q I get no error messages. I did check the paths, and the path to the xmobarrc file is in the PATH.

This is the xmonad.hs command I use to launch

```
main = do
  xmproc <- spawnPipe "xmobar"
  xmonad defaults
```

The xmobarrc file is the same as the default config file:

```
Config { font = "-misc-fixed-*-*-*-*-10-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"
       , additionalFonts = []
       , borderColor = "black"
       , border = TopB
       , bgColor = "black"
       , fgColor = "grey"
       , alpha = 255
       , position = Top
       , textOffset = -1
       , iconOffset = -1
       , lowerOnStart = True
       , pickBroadest = False
       , persistent = False
       , hideOnStart = False
       , iconRoot = "."
       , allDesktops = True
       , overrideRedirect = True
       , commands = [ Run Weather "EGPF" ["-t","<station>: <tempC>C",
                                          "-L","18","-H","25",
                                          "--normal","green",
                                          "--high","red",
                                          "--low","lightblue"] 36000
                    , Run Network "eth0" ["-L","0","-H","32",
                                          "--normal","green","--high","red"] 10
                    , Run Network "eth1" ["-L","0","-H","32",
                                          "--normal","green","--high","red"] 10
                    , Run Cpu ["-L","3","-H","50",
                               "--normal","green","--high","red"] 10
                    , Run Memory ["-t","Mem: <usedratio>%"] 10
                    , Run Swap [] 10
                    , Run Com "uname" ["-s","-r"] "" 36000
                    , Run Date "%a %b %_d %Y %H:%M:%S" "date" 10
                    ]
       , sepChar = "%"
       , alignSep = "}{"
       , template = "%cpu% | %memory% * %swap% | %eth0% - %eth1% }\
                    \{ <fc=#ee9a00>%date%</fc>| %EGPF% | %uname%"
       }
```

Any help?

Comment: You are not using the `xmproc` at all. It should some how go into a `logHook`.

Comment: Look at this: https://xmonad.github.io/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Hooks-StatusBar.html

Comment: @rajashekar This xmobar configuration has a `template` which does **not** include `StdinReader`, thus all items can be displayed without piping from XMonad, therefore it suffices to just launch it right away.